# Highlighting 3 Cells If Condition Met

Tags: excel

I have a question regarding conditional formatting in Excel.

I have a sheet that acts as a calendar for my team members whereby calendar dates are in row 1 and each person’s name in column A. Each person occupies 3 rows unmerged, so the first name occupies rows 2 to 4, the next person 5 to 7, and so on. If the person will not be at work on a particular day, a “out of office” will be written on the respective first row. Assuming that 1 January occupies column B and that the first person will be out of office then, the value of cell B2 will be “out of office”. Using conditional formatting, I was able to highlight B2:B4 without issues. However, I was only able to do this for a single person.

I would like to know if there is a way of extending some conditional formatting formula to all 20 members so that I do not have to do the same thing for another 19 times (more if new members join).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if any cell in column `B` contains "out of office" then this cell and the next 2 cells below shall be formatted? Or in other words a cell shall be formatted if itself or the cell 1 row above or the cell 2 rows above contains "out of office"?

This can be achieved using the following conditionla formatting rule for whole column `B`:

[image]

Conditional formatting rule based on formula:

```
=OR(B1="out of office",B1048576="out of office",B1048575="out of office")
```

Background: In CF the references are like a carousel. So what in `B1` is

```
=OR(B1="out of office",B1048576="out of office",B1048575="out of office")
```

will be in `B2` then

```
=OR(B2="out of office",B1="out of office",B1048576="out of office")
```

(`B1048576` plus 1 row = `B1`)

and in `B3` then

```
=OR(B3="out of office",B2="out of office",B1="out of office")
```

Comment: This method works brilliantly. I would never have thought of things this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Conditional Formatting **Formula**, then you can use the following code to retrieve the value from the current or previous row in the pattern 2, 5, 8, 11, etc:

```
INDEX(A:A, 3*INT((ROW()-2)/3)+2, 1)
```

To break it down:  Using `INDEX(A:A` and `, 1)` will get us a row from Column A (of course, this moves across as your Format Condition does) - the row itself is specified by the ungainly mess in the middle: `3 * INT((ROW() - 2) / 3) + 2`

Putting that kludge into plain-text: Start with the current row, subtract 2, round *down* to a multiple of 3, then add 2 again

```
Row | Subtract 2 | Round down to 3 | Add 2
  1 |     -1     |         -3      |   -1
  2 |      0     |          0      |    2
  3 |      1     |          0      |    2
  4 |      2     |          0      |    2
  4 |      3     |          3      |    5
 .. |    ....    |        ....     |   ..
 28 |     26     |         24      |   26
 29 |     27     |         27      |   29
 30 |     28     |         27      |   29
 31 |     29     |         27      |   29
 32 |     30     |         30      |   32
```

So - you can now just apply whole-column conditional formatting, with a formula something like this:

```
=INDEX(A:A, 3*INT((ROW()-2)/3)+2, 1) = "Out of Office"
```

And it will apply to blocks of 3 rows at a time in each column, starting at Row 2 (or -1)

Comment: I have tested this method and it works very well. Thank you.

Comment: This clearly also has its usage. Using this the "out of office" will only noted if it is in first rows of the three used rows for a person. In my answer every occurrence of  "out of office" starts the three used rows for a person. So both answers differs in this.